# Discarding characters in C?

Tags: c

I'm doing intro to C and I need to write a program that prompts the user to enter in characters, an equal sign, and an integer. I need to use `getchar()` until the `'='` then `scanf()` for the integer. The program should then output only the integer back to the user.

Right now it prints out unnecessary code re the location for every character input, then at the end outputs the correct integer. This is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define EQUAL '=' 
int main(void)
{ 
    char ch;
    int integer = 0;

    printf("Enter some text, an equal sign and an integer:\n");
    while ((ch = getchar())!= '\n') //while not end of line
    {
        if (ch == EQUAL){
            scanf("%d", &integer);
        }
        printf("The integer you entered is: %d\n", integer);
    }

return 0;  
}
```

I can't find an example and need clarification on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you post your code as text please? Cut & paste it into the post and hit the "code" button at the top of the edit field. It's hard to debug an image.

Comment: Simply pull the `printf` statement outside of your `while` loop. (+1 for posting a MCVE).

Comment: @A.S.H If they pull the `printf` out of the while loop, it will always print that the entered an integer even if they didn't.

Comment: @Schwern you mean it will say *you entered 0*? Then they need to check the result of scanf. Lot of additional checking and things can be done as well. My note simply helps to fix the issue stated in the OP :)

Comment: @A.S.H Please don't give incomplete or misleading advice to new programmers.

Comment: @Schwern My advice was none of those. please, let us avoid a useless debate because it is opinion-based.

Comment: @Schwern Hey guys thanks for the responses. I've tried inserting curly brackets but it's still outputting the following:                                            Enter some text, an equal sign and an integer:
num = 23
The integer you entered is: 0
The integer you entered is: 0
The integer you entered is: 0
The integer you entered is: 0
The integer you entered is: 23
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: @Sera Update the code in the question with what you've got now and let's see.

Comment: @Schwern okay updated w/ curly brackets.

Comment: @Sera Notice the `printf` is outside the `if` block. That means the same as it was before, it just has braces around it now. To think about it the other way, remove the `if` block and what do you have?  `while(...) { printf(...) }`.

Comment: @Schwern Ah, got it! Thanks. Forgot to put it back after playing around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got bit by a gotcha in C.  The problem is this:

```
if( ch == EQUAL )
    scanf("%d", &integer);
    printf("The integer you entered is %d\n", integer);
```

`if` with no braces will only include the single statement following it.  That code is really this:

```
if( ch == EQUAL ) {
    scanf("%d", &integer);
}
printf("The integer you entered is %d\n", integer);
```

To avoid this gotcha, I would recommend two things:

- Always indent your code properly.
- Never use if, else, or while without braces.

gcc supports a warning about this, `-Wmisleading-indentation`.

For more gotchas like this read ["C Traps And Pitaflls"](http://literateprogramming.com/ctraps.pdf) by Andrew Koenig.

Comment: I bet Sera is a Python programmer